# FF & Chrome: Text bounding box difference in Windows/Linux

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I'm trying to position several text elements using `position:absolute`. However, it seems that both on Firefox and on Chrome, the bounding box of the text elements is of a different size in Windows and in Linux.

[image]

I've extracted a simple test case which is available here:
http://share.shmichael.com/html/event.html

I've tried all kinds of alignment tricks, and specifying the height manually, but couldn't get it to work nicely. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does both system have the same fonts installed? maybe the fonts are slightly different here and there.

Comment: Must be font rendering on target system; the example is using @font-face with OTF linked fonts.

Comment: @pharalle - What's wrong with OTF?

@aularon - I don't have this font installed on either machine, it is pulled from the server. You can try it yourself.

Comment: Nothing wrong with OTF whatsoever - just pointing out it was the same font on both OS'es :)

Comment: Off-topic, but I hope your actual page has dir=rtl on the html element instead of using CSS for it. As for the screenshots, I'm also suspecting font rendering. Example, here's Chrome/Linux: http://stommepoes.nl/tempstackoverflowscreenshot.png and I should be getting the @ font-face font.

Answer (score 0):

Under **#event_list h1** add *line-height:26px;* to match your font-size. This should fix your problem.

You might also want to add *margin:0;padding:0;* under **h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6**.